# Problema em renderizar múltiplos objetos em OpenGL Legacy (GLFW)

Tags: c, c++, opengl

Estou tentando renderizar um círculo e um retângulo, e ambos terão movimento independente (Remake de Pong), mas o problema é que o glTranslatef() de um está influenciando no outro, se um ir para a direita, o outro também vai. Colocando para imprimir os valores  das variáveis no console, aparenta estar tudo certo.

```cpp
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(bola.x, bola.y, 0);
CriarBola(0.5, 24);

glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(13, player.pos, 0);
CriarQuadrado(player.larg, player.alt);
```

Creio que o erro não esteja vindo das funções abaixo, mas vou colocá-las:

```cpp
//Função de criar o retangulo
void CriarQuadrado(float larg, float alt)
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-larg, alt, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-larg,-alt, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(larg, -alt, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(larg, alt, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}
```

```cpp
//Função de criar o círculo, que é feito a partir de triângulos
void CriarTriangulo(float v1[], float v2[], float v3[])
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3fv(v1);
    glVertex3fv(v2);
    glVertex3fv(v3);
    glEnd();
}

void CriarBola(float raio, float faces)
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    float ang = 2 * PI / faces;
    for (short x = 0; x < faces; x++) {
        float v1[3]{ raio * std::cos((x + 1) * ang), raio * std::sin((x + 1) * ang), 0 };
        float v2[3]{ 0, 0, 0 };
        float v3[3]{ raio * std::cos(x * ang), raio * std::sin(x * ang), 0 };
        CriarTriangulo(v1, v2, v3);
    }
}
```

[Deixarei todo o codigo desse projeto no repl.it](https://repl.it/@GustavoGLD/Pong-Incomplete#main.cpp)

Comment: você está utilizando uma versão do OpenGL que já faz mas de década que foi marcada como deprecated, procure por modern OpenGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ainda não posso comentar então vai por aqui mesmo. Será, só hipoteticamente falando já que não lidei ainda com OpenGl. Eu ficaria mais desconfiado, pelo seu comentário que o glTranslatef() seria para rotacionar as coordenadas globais o que afetaria todas as transformações antes do render. Normalmente você passaria o objeto ou eu modificaria a estrutura que compõem o as coordenadas o objeto e e chamaria para renderizar.

Pensando nisso, dei uma olhada na doc da Khronos Group:
 https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml

Ali na doc tem essa referencia que colarei a abaixo: 
**" If the matrix mode is either GL_MODELVIEW or GL_PROJECTION, all objects drawn after a call to glTranslate are translated.
Use glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix to save and restore the untranslated coordinate system. "**

Basicamente se você não isolar as coornadas que você alterar na matriz irão afetar todos os objetos posteriores criados.

Veja se isso não da uma ajuda, lembra muito uma operação push pop no assembly.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/General_OpenGL:_Transformations

A cima tem um link que mostra um pouco como usar

E abaixo um video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYD6zDiI_3A

Se isso resolver da um feedback, e coloca como resolver e como isso funciona, seria interessante saber.

Acredito que com isso você consegue resolver.

Comment: E de verdade, se der certo ou outra solução compartilha ai, não terei tempo de testar o codigo, mas se você compartilhar e eu ou outra pessoa precisar no futuro, já terá um material disponível.